# Concatenate TimeStamp to File using Batch file

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

I have created two batch file that are working. Here is the outline

- First Batch Calls another batch file
- The second batch file changes to the directory on the application where the utility and command path to backup an asset resides, does the backup and places the file in C:\

I simple did a cd/ after the CALL command used to start second batch file to return to the path where the backup file is archived.

How do I use

```
set backupFilename=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
```

or other function to Concatenate to the backup file?
FileName_05-21-2015:09:30 Pm.txt

I am getting an error that the file does not exist when in fact it does.  My intention is to use AT command or Schtask command to schedule this backup process every week. I will also appreciate more descriptive application of this commands too with time stamp for every backup completed on schedule

Comment: I don't think the filename has colons in it, so please correct that.  Colons are not allowed in filenames in Windows.

Comment: I only have the date part but added in the original question the in case there is a way to get that piece to work as well. I want the Date appended. But the issue with date is still not working for me. saying it cannot locate or the file does not exist when it actually exist because the second batch job actually ran. I assume the part that is having the issue is the point where the First batch begins after the second batch finishes.

Comment: You'll probably need to post more of the script(s) for us to really understand what you're trying to do and what's happening.  It's not clear to me what you mean by "concatenate to the backup file."  Strings are concatenated, not files, and we don't know what string you to be concatenated, but since the filename you seem to be wanting to concatenate has colons in it, and colons can't be used in filenames, readers aren't sure what you're needing.

Comment: FYI this is not a forum but a Q&A site. One of the differences is that posters should leave out chit-chat that is not question related (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)). I already edited the irrelevant material out of your post, it was triaged by multiple people for review as needing improvement.

Comment: I have fixed this issue with Date and here is the flow
@echo off

CALL PCSDEV.bat

echo Starting Service change directory to C:\
REM Change directory back to the location where the file is archived
cd\

set HR=%time:~0,2%
set HR=%Hr: =0% 
set HR=%HR: =%
ren Test.out.isx Test.out-%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%.isx

cd ISTOOLBK.  The only help I will need with this code is how to update the %HR..to come out as 12 hours format. Currently, it comes out in 24 hour format. My final file looks like  Test.out-20152605_1529.isx  instead of  0329.isx PM